# Retrieve user's name and email after aws-amplify federated login with Google

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using aws-amplify to log my users into my site. I'm using

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Google'});
```

to log them in. When they click through with their email, they are added to a user pool where their username looks something like

```
Google_12345678901234567890
```

and their email and name are inside the profile when you click on that Google username in the user pool. How can I access the user's name and email through my Angular code?

I've tried

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
```

and

```
Auth.currentSession()
```

both of which don't hold that info, along with
`Auth.currentUserInfo()`
which returns empty, and

```
Auth.userAttributes()
```

which doesn't seem to work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kinda answered my own question. After authenticating with

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Google'});
```

I ran the following code:

```
Auth.currentSession()
    .then(data => {
        let idToken = data.getIdToken();
        console.dir(idToken);
        let email = idToken.payload.email;
        console.log(email);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

All the info sits in the id token and can be viewed through

```
console.dir(idToken);
```

Comment: It's good but do not return the user profile picture/name, only email.. do u have any idea for how to do so?

Comment: Indeed! In your user pool, under "federation", go to attribute mapping, and there set the map between the oauth data you want to the Congito response name.
lmk if it didn't work out

Comment: alright! Thank you for your quick response, now i've added picture as Google Attribute and Picture from the dropdown from userpool attribute, but where do I retrieve it? Because if I log my Auth.currentSession() it isnt there?

Comment: I am trying to figure this out too. How can I access the google profile image?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Eyal Cohen, you need to map attributes by going to attribute mapping and then retrieve it as follows:

```
const func = async() => {
      user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      user = user.attributes; //all attributes exist in the attributes field   
}
        
func();
```